How to use appsettings in Azure Container App?
Currently we are migrating our .NET Framework WEB APIs to .NET 8. Along with that, we are migrating from service fabric to Azure Container App.
We want to use app setings from AppSettings.json file in our code, but we are not able to find the steps to implement/use it in Azure Container App.
We have followed below steps to use AppSettings.json so far:

Changes in Docker File to copy AppSettings.json in root folder:


 From mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build  
 ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
 WORKDIR /src
 COPY ["DummyWebApi/DummyWebApi.csproj", "DummyWebApi/"]
 COPY ["DummyWebApi/appsettings.json", "/appsettings.json"]



Code changes to use app setting
 private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;        
 private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

 public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)        
 {
     _logger = logger;
     _configuration = configuration;
 }

 [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
 public string Get()
 { 
        string? appSettingValue = _configuration["appSettingKey"];               
        return $"dummy response + {appSettingValue}";
 }


After deployment, I am getting below error



Activation Failed --> The TargetPort 8080 does not match the listening
port 5000


Please suggest if I am missing anything in above steps?
Or what steps should be followed to use AppSettings.json in Azure Container App?

Container app? How does your app look ?Can u please share the folder structure of your app.If possible please share your code repo.

What are files you have in your container app ?

AFAIK,even Container app uses appsettings.json file to set Appsettings.

Please post code as text, not images.

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems, as already stated in previuos comment.. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

Hi @Harshitha, It has simple ASP.NET Core Web API structure (.NET 8). I am using default controller for testing WeatherForecastController. I have dockerfile at solution level.

HI @Harshitha, can you please share how to set app setting values in azure container app ?

Hi @RuiJarimba/ @Piery, Thanks for the suggestions. I have updated the question with text.

@BhartiTijare -  Are you sure the issue is with the appsettings? I can see the error is related to the PORT configuration.

@Harshitha Yes, it seems to be. Because I am getting this port issue only when I am deploying code where I am trying to get value from app setting.
It will be helpful if you can help me to get idea on how to set app settings in Azure Container App ?

Sure..will try with your code and let you know.If possible please share your code repo.

How you are deploying your app?

@BhartiTijare - Please confirm once you are using which publish option?

@BhartiTijare - I am able to deploy the app and retrieve the keys without any issue with your code. Output.The only difference I have with my docker file is I have not included Docker File to copy AppSettings.json in root folder. By default the deployment copies the appsettings.json file in the wwwroot directory.No need to make any changes in docker file.

@Harshitha Can you please share your repo to see if I am missing anything in code ?
Also, anything specific done on Azure Container App or Azure Container Registry side to use app setting?

If you confirm this is what you are looking for ,I can post an answer with the details.

Hi @Harshitha, yes, please post your answer with details. I am looking for the same. Thanks!!

@BhartiTijare - Check EXPOSE in my docker file.

Configuring settings in Container App is much similar and easy as Configuring them in the Normal Web Apps.

By default, the appsettings.json file is deployed to the application root directory.

My .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>****</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

My Docker file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ContainerAppSetting/ContainerAppSetting.csproj", "ContainerAppSetting/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./ContainerAppSetting/ContainerAppSetting.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ContainerAppSetting"
RUN dotnet build "./ContainerAppSetting.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build


FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./ContainerAppSetting.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ContainerAppSetting.dll"]


Retrieved the values using your code.


string? appSettingValue = _configuration["appSettingKey"];

Output (value set in appsettings.json file:


You can override the values set in appsettings.json file from the Container App => Containers => Edit and deploy => Environment variables section.



Create a new Environment variable with the same key name (which you want to override).


Overriden value:


Thank you so much @Harshitha. It’s working for me now. The only step missing from my end was adding environment variable in container.
So conclusion is ‘if you are using app settings, you have to add environment variable with same name while deploying container in ACA’

Yes, the name has to match with the key from appsetiings.json file.

@BhartiTijare - Even you can add new keys which are not in appsettings.json file and retrieve in code directly.

@BhartiTijare you might accept the answer to end the discussion.

what about hierarchical appsettings values?

@ShawndeWet -  Can you add more details about the ask?

I have an appsetting in a hierarchical format like so: "EnvironmentConfiguration": {
"EncryptionKey": "mykey"}.  How do I specify this environment variable in Azure Container Apps?  (it does not allow the use of colons (:))

Did you try _ underscore/double unserscore __.

I have tried the double underscores, but I can confirm this does not work.  I have defined an environment variable named ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection, but in my code I am logging the value with Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), but the log entry shows an empty value.

Can you please add new post with all the details.
